# Couchdb size management

Tags: node.js, couchdb, nosql

I have a couch database called **restaurants.couch** and once a week I would
*Compact Database* and the file size will go from 20MB to 11MB.

I see that the older versions are gone - which I don't need.

However, I notice that the **.restaurants_design** folder size is over 100MB
and there are 30+ **.view** files in here.

I executed *Compact Views* and *Clean Up Views*, and it reduced it to 8MB and to just 1 .view file. My app also ran a little faster.

My questions :

1) Why does **.restaurants_design** get so large ? What's the reason. It's just a view.

2) What's the benefit of *Compact Views* and *Clean Up Views* ( besides file size reduction ) ?

3) What are the side effects of *Compact Views* and *Clean Up Views* ? Will I ever regret doing this if I don't need versioning ?

4) How often should *Compact Database, Compact Views, and Clean Up Views*
be performed if the app does not really need versioning other than a simple
nosql database with some views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. CouchDb caches the view query result on disk for indexing to speed to the query. So if you have lots of views, and user query them with different parameters, they will be cached.
2. [Compact Views](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Compaction) - `View indexes on disk are named after their MD5 hash of the view definition. When you change a view, old indexes remain on disk. To clean up all outdated view indexes (files named after the MD5 representation of views, that does not exist anymore) you can trigger a view cleanup:`. [Clean Up Views](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#View_Cleanup) however, remove old views caches, since if you update a view, the old result of the view is still on disk.
3. The side effects is the next person who query the view will take longer time since CouchDB will need to rebuild the caches. `Compact Views` and `Clean Up Views` does not effect versioning, but `Compact Database` does.
4. The frequency really depend on the way your application work and the limitation of you deployment setup. However if you really want to disable versioning, try look into [_revs_limit](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_database_API) setting, so you can just set a limit of revision for all documents.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful! When you say change "change view" does that mean a document in the view changed as a result of an an update or change as in Map/Reduce function ? as documents get udpated, does the view also grow since it has to "re-index" ?

Comment: 'Change view' here means you change the view design document (the M/R), this will make the the next first query slow, since it need to warm-up the view. The indexes for the view does grow when a documents get updated.